# What is the correct way to use AsyncStorage to update state in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to make a GET request to a server to retrieve a list of products in JSON form. I then want to put the data into AsyncStorage so I can display the products in the view. What's the correct way to do this?

**What I've researched:**

on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html , in the example, they explain how to retrieve a value from AsyncStorage, not set it and retrieve it at the same time

**What I have:**

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchProducts()
    this._loadInitialState().done();
}

_loadInitialState = async () => {
    try {
        var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('products')
        if (value != null) {
            this.setState({products: value});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error setting product list");
    }
}

fetchProducts() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/products",{
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then((response) => (response.json()))
    .then((data) => setProductList(data)); 

}

setProductList(json_data) {
    Async.setItem('products': json_data);
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.products) 
    //render view
}
```

-> this.state.products is null and I know for sure the server returns a response through curl. I'm new to react-native so perhaps my thinking is off. Could someone explain the correct way to do this or suggest an alternative method?

**What I know**
Async storage is a key value store where an app can place its data. This data can be put from async storage into the object's state and the view will update accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting and getting from async storage, you can just set it to state once you get the data from your fetch request:

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchProducts()
}

fetchProducts() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/products",{
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then((response) => (response.json()))
    .then((data) => setProductList(data)); 

}

setProductList(json_data) {
    this.setState({ products: json_data }, () => {     //Here
      Async.setItem('products': json_data);
    }
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.products) 
    //render view
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just changed 

 setProductList(json_data) {
  this.setState({ products: json_data })
     AsyncStorage.setItem('products': json_data);
 }

and it worked!