# AsyncStorage data's are not getting updated with new data in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update the data's of `asynchStorage` in react native, but the data are not getting updated.

I followed these threads  and did the same way, But could not find where it is getting wrong. 
Although if i try to add only two objects that works fine but when i try to add `product` to  `productData`, it only returns one old data, the `productData` doesn't get updated.
Here is my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/73ftg295/23/

Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you.

1. [What is the correct way to use AsyncStorage to update state in React-Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495412/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-asyncstorage-to-update-state-in-react-native)
2. [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

**Here is my snippet**

```
static addToCart(id,name,qty,price){

//Storing the data into a variable 
        let product={
            id:id,
            name:name,
            qty:qty,
            price:price,

        };

      //Generate rowid for the product
      product.rowId = this.generateHash(product);

   //Calling asyncStorage function     
 AsyncStorage.getItem('CART').then((data) => {

                    //Check if the data exist or not
            if (data !== null){

                //Convert the data to an object and store to productData variable
                let productData= JSON.parse(data);

                //Check if the product with the rowid exist in the store or not
                if (this.checkIfExist(product.rowId)){

                //If exist increment the quantity of the product
                    productData[product.rowId].qty += product.qty;
                }else{

                    //If does not exist then add this new product to the existing products
                    productData[product.rowId] = product;  // ERROR HERE !! the new record is not getting added to the productData


                }

                //Update the storage with new data
                AsyncStorage.setItem("CART", JSON.stringify(productData)).done();
                cartResponse = productData;
            }else{
            //If data is null then there is no previous product availabe. Add first product
                let cartItem ={};
                cartItem[product.rowId] =product;
                AsyncStorage.setItem("CART", JSON.stringify(cartItem)).done();
            }

            //If everything works fine then return true
            return true;
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log('Error occurred while adding product to cart',error);
            return false;
        });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage is asychonours so you have call with await like this:

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

this is doc from Facebook, it's very clear to understand: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#docsNav